Restriction on automorphism group of Conway's 99-graph
I suppose that the last and best restriction is given in [1] (Crnkovic, Maksimovic, 2020), where the final Theorem 7.3 states that $|G|=2^a3^b$ with $b\in\{0,1\}$ and a few additional conditions. It seems however, that this result does not take (explicitly) into account the observation from [2] (Makhnev, Minakova, 2004) and recalled in [3] (Cesarz, Woldar, 2023) that $|G|$ has at most one factor 2.
Combining these results together I observe the restriction can be refined to the form: $|G|=2^a3^b$ with $a,b\in\{0,1\}$ and $a+b\leq 1$ (as $|G|=6$ is excluded in [1]). In other words, the putative srg(99,14,1,2):

is asymmetric,
[or] has the automorphism group $\mathbb{Z}_2$,
[or] has the automorphism group $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (without fixed points).

Is it a correct conclusion?

The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.02978 you link to is from 2023, I would imagine it has the most up to date information about this topic.

But what you claim seems much more than what is claimed in arxiv.org/abs/2308.02978. For example, according to that paper, it seems possible that the automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}_7$, no?

@Sam Hopkins Exactly, but arxiv.org/abs/2308.02978 seems not to take into account the result of doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2010.10.005 which excludes 7 as a prime factor of |G|. So it is an interesting research on the graph structure, but the result is probably not up to date.

Maybe you should try contacting the authors of the 2023 preprint directly then?
